# Custom text with pin on Google Maps

Tags: google-maps

I'm attempting to add a pin to Google maps with custom text next to it. I haven't had to do this in some time, and my Google-Fu hasn't been overly helpful. I have it set up so the pin shows shows up, but nothing I've tried to add the text works. It simply removes the pin. When I'm using is this:

```
"http://maps.google.com/maps/place/" + dLatitude + "," + dLongitude + "/@" + dLatitude + "," + dLongitude + ",15z/data=!3m1!1e3!4m2!3m1!1s0x0:0x0";
```

Any help on adding my text would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using Google Static Maps, you are limited to single letters when adding text on a marker (the pin). Refer to `label` under [Marker Styles](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/staticmaps/#MarkerStyles).

If you need to put more text, I suggest making use of [info windows](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/infowindows). This is not part of the Static Maps API and you will need to follow the steps [here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/tutorial).